# Sorting on two columns with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Every week, I receive data to process, so that they are more presentable, I have to do a job.

Each week being the same task, with different data, I decided to automate it so as not to waste time

I have to sort column B first, and according to column B, sort column H, between each sort, a separation by two lines.

Very important, it is often possible that on the same market (Column B) there are two different fees (Column H), so if the fees are different, it should also skip two rows

Basically, the result Im trying to get since 1 week is :

- Sort alphabetically by column B
- Separate each step by two line breaks
- Separate the fees, and if on the same market there are several fees, separate by two line breaks too

Here is the code I was able to do:

```
Sub step()
    
'

    
    Dim lngRow&, i&
    Dim strMarket$
    lngRow& = Worksheets("DATA").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    With Worksheets("DATA").AutoFilter.Sort
        With .SortFields
            .Clear
            .Add2 Key:=Range("H1:H" & lngRow&), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        End With
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
       With .SortFields
        .Clear
           .Add2 Key:=Range("B1:B" & lngRow&), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        End With
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With

    For i = lngRow& To 3 Step -1
        strMarket$ = Worksheets("DATA").Cells(i, 2)
        If Worksheets("DATA").Cells(i, 2).Offset(-1) <> strMarket$ Then Rows(i).Insert: Rows(i).Insert
    Next i
```

Here is the data I receive :

[image]

Here is the final result I want with VBA :

[image]

Thank you in advance for those who will help me, I have searched the internet but no similar answer I could find .... I've been stressing for a week to find the solution ....

Answer (score 0):

Your second sort is overriding your first one because you clear the existing sort fields. You want something like:

```
With Worksheets("DATA").AutoFilter.Sort
    With .SortFields
        .Clear
        .Add2 Key:=Range("B1:B" & lngRow&), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Add2 Key:=Range("H1:H" & lngRow&), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    End With
    .Header = xlYes
    .Apply
End With
For i = lngRow& To 3 Step -1
    If Worksheets("DATA").Cells(i - 1, 2) <> Worksheets("DATA").Cells(i, 2) Or Worksheets("DATA").Cells(i - 1, "H") <> Worksheets("DATA").Cells(i, "H")Then Rows(i).Resize(2).Insert
Next i
```

Comment: I tried with this code, but one more time , it doesn't skip 2 rows on the column H ....

Comment: You still need your code after this to insert the two blank rows but you'll want to check column H and column B.

Comment: yes I added the blank rows, but the thing is that the code don't separate fees in column H, I need to separate column B, and after separate to column H if there is more than one fee in the same market

Comment: You need to adjust your code that inserts rows to do it if column B is not the value from the row above **or** column H is not the value from the row above.

Comment: I don't really understrand how to do this, this was my initial question .. how to find a solution for this

Comment: Still not working, i have the same problem, the column H do not create blanks rows

Comment: I mean, it separates, but only according to column B

Comment: Nope, works fine here sorting on both and separating at any change in either column.

Comment: Ok you was right, I had another vba that blocked the filtering
Anyway, thanks again to you! You are a life saver! Since the time I was looking for the solution ... And you found it quickly !

Good day to you !